# how to extract data from a value text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was inherited a query and part of the query is to remove characters to get certain characters.

So here is the string `"Added Keyword (Group) 'ABC-ABC-ABC-ABC' to 'Incoming Fax  - 4/3/2017 1:57:21 PM - From: [Fax Name or #s], To: [2140000000]"`

Here is my query:

```
SUBSTRING(column1,CHARINDEX('to ''',column1)+19,LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(column1)))-CHARINDEX('''',(column1))-19) as Received
```

The end result is I just want the Date and Time which is the `4/3/2017 1:57:21 PM`

I'm using SSMS 2014

Comment: can you provide 2string and its desire output ? than i can help u

Comment: Hello, the string is something like this below (i've removed user's info)  Added Keyword (Group) 'ABC-ABC-ABC-ABC' to 'Incoming Fax  - 4/3/2017 12:15:36 PM - From: [SOMEONE or #s], To: [214818000]' ...    and in this string i only want to get the Date and Time, the rest can be removed.

Comment: is Fax key word always there ?

Comment: Yes, the "Fax -" and the "- From" always there

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide the complete starting string and the exact result you want. Mysql has regex functions which should be able to do this easily.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I'm new to SQL and still trying to understanding from different pieces. I've edited my question.

Comment: Hi @user7681605 I added a query below. Try to make use of the same. I believe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change +4 or -4 as you need. now you will have your desire output

```
SUBSTRING(INSTR(column1,'Fax',1)+4,(INSTR(column1,'Form:',1)-INSTR(column1,'Fax',1)-4))
```

Comment: I tried this but it says that substr and position is not identified as the built in function. Sorry, I'm still learning SQL from different pieces. The SQL I'm using is SSMS 2014, hope that help the type of sql i'm using

Comment: @user7681605 can you try now ?

Comment: thank you. I play around with it a little and were able to get the value I wanted using code. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of below code:

```
    DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) ='Added Keyword (Group) ''ABC-ABC-ABC-ABC'' to ''Incoming Fax  - 4/3/2017 1:57:21 PM - From: [Fax Name or #s], To: [2140000000]'
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@String),20)as Received
    --SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',column1),20)as Received
```

Comment: thank you too for the code. I was able to pull the value I wanted using your and knowledge's code above. Both different but works well. Thanks again.